# My Modern Sharepoint Calendar is hiding current events, how can I fix it?

Tags: modern-experience, calendar

I am transforming our old Sharepoint Calendar to the modern version and after making the new version official, the users and I stumbled upon this problem. The events ending the current week and the previous ones are hidden. You can see in the list right after that I have multiple events during this and previous weeks :

[image: List of events from the calendar]

But when displayed in the calendar, they are hidden. I even created a test event from the calendar, which displayed in the list but not on the calendar :
[image: Calendar view]

Has anyone ever had this problem and if so, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem! Someone seems to have messed with the items display and made items ending in 7 days or less not displayed...

[image: Calendar view editing]